# Prove that a ring $R$ has a unique 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Problem:** Prove that a ring $R$ has a unique 1.

**My attempt:** Suppose we have another unit denoted by $1'$. Then $\forall a \in R, 1.a = a = 1'.a \Rightarrow 1.a = 1'.a$. Apply cancellation law for both side we have $1=1'$. Is this proof completely? Thank all!

Comment: Cancellation laws only hold in rings with no zero divisors, so your proof is not valid for rings with zero divisors.

Comment: So, we couldn't apply cancellation law here. Is there any way to prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cancellation law is in full generality only applicable to nonzero divisiors $a$.

If $1,1'$ are two ones, then $1\cdot 1'=1$ since $1'$ is a one, and $1\cdot 1' = 1'$ since $1$ is a one. So $1=1'$.

Comment: We supposed $1$ and $1'$ are unit of a ring $R$, so I think we couldn't conclude that $1 = 1'$ from $1.1' = 1$ and $1.1' = 1'$.

Comment: @Minh Because $1$ is a unit, we know that $1\cdot 1' = 1'$. Also, because $1'$ is a unit, we know that $1\cdot 1' = 1$. We also know that if $a=b$ and $a=c$, that $b=c$. This is a general rule in logic.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof doesn't work because you don't necessarily have a cancellation law in a ring.  (For example, $4 \cdot 5 \equiv 2 \cdot 5 \operatorname{mod} 10$ but $2 \neq 4 \operatorname{mod} 10$.)  But if you consider the product $1 \cdot 1'$, I think you'll see why you have uniqueness.